# php curl access unknown url ,Why curl_exec no return false,echo should output failed

Tags: php, curl

[image]

curl access unknown url,Why curl_exec return true.It should output failed.

Comment: Don't post code as images. Copy/paste the code to your question!

Comment: $url = 'http://fvsfdfsdfsdfsfse.com';
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    print_r($result);
    echo curl_error($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    if($result == false) {
        echo 'failed';
        return;
    }
    echo 'succeed';
    return;

Comment: Edit your _question_ to remove the image and include your code. It's pretty unreadable as a comment.

Comment: **1.** The code you posted looks slightly different from the screen shot. **2.** Your code does exactly what it should. It throws an error: _"Could not resolve host: fvsfdfsdfsdfsfse.com"_ and then echoes _"failed"_. What's your actual issue?

Comment: yeah.Your answer is what I want, however, what I get is succeed.I'm confused.

Comment: You already got three close votes. You need to update your _question_ to include the code or it will most likely be closed soon. And since I can't reproduce your issue, I can't really help you.

Comment: It's ok.thank your very much.I am code run sometimes good and bad.My code runs fine and sometimes bad.Just occur error :Could not resolve host: fvsfdfsdfsdfsfsefailed.

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = 'http://fvsfdfsdfsdfsfse';
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
print_r($result);
echo curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);

if($result == false) {
    echo 'failed';
    return;
}
echo 'succeed';
return;
```

Comment: run result:1.1succeed;2.Could not resolve host: fvsfdfsdfsdfsfsefailed.

Answer (score 0):

you probably use a shitty DNS that doesn't actually return NXDOMAIN for non-existing domains, but redirects you to some shitty ads-server instead. DNS's doing this includes OpenDNS, Freenom DNS, and some DNSs set by viruses, iirc.

try doing

```
curl_setopt_array($ch,array(CURLOPT_DNS_LOCAL_IP4=>'8.8.8.8',CURLOPT_DNS_LOCAL_IP6=>'2001:4860:4860:0:0:0:0:8888'));
```

first. this should force curl to use GoogleDNS, which doesn't do shit like that.

but note that these flags were first added to PHP in version 7.0.7

Comment: I was hijack by isp.I modified code,php 7.1version,cleanup browser data,cleanup dns,but...